# Varnish Cache Miss issue during module upload in magento market place

Tags: php, magento2

I have developed an extension in Magento 2 for product details page which i want to upload in marketplace. But i am getting varnish cache miss issue report from marketplace. I haven't written cachable="false" in any of my layout xml file. 
Your assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance